# An error with model.save of keras "can't pickle _thread.RLock objects"

Tags: keras, constants, pickle

I am using the following model in keras:

```
inputs = Input(shape=( img_width, img_height))** 

inpFloat = Input(shape =(1,1))**

in0= Lambda(lambda x: inpFloat*x)(inputs)**

model =Model([inputs, inpFloat],in0)**
```

When I do the following prediction

```
xx = np.random.rand(1, 150, 1025)**

y1=np.array([2.0])**
y1 =np.expand_dims(y1,axis=1)**

y1 = np.expand_dims(y1, axis=2)**
print(model.predict([xx,y1]))**
```

It works. However, when I perform model.save, I get the following error:

> rv = reductor(4)
>
> TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

I assume it relates to the way I use Lambda function (if I replace the constant with a number it works)

Any ideas?

Comment: define a function and don't use lambda here. pickl can't work with a object defined in local scope (I suspect its treated as local scope here.)

Comment: Thanks . Just, if I replace the lambda with the function , I should save it as well (in a dictionary) shouldn't I?